# Accessing Database Outside Local Network For a School Project

Tags: database, apache, xampp, mariadb

I am working with a group of students, and we are required to work together to create a website. The website is pretty simple, but we are stuck accessing the database from different networks. We are all using Xampp as our local database and working from our own homes.

My proposal is the following:

1. Have a local phpmyadmin(like usually) and import the same tables for everyone
2. opting for paid/free database services
3. hosting our database

I thought It would be better to import the tables for everyone instead of doing something else as the project is tiny, but I am unsure. Any feedback would be appreciated, and any more solutions are welcome.

Comment: How are you synchronizing the rest of the website (everything, but the database) within your group?   How many changes to the database  structure are you expecting?

Comment: I'd recommend you to use local databases for local development (if your code runs local use a local database). Let's say you share your code via git, svn or even dropbox. Put an sql file next to your code (drops all tables, create tables and insert shared test data in that file). On every mayor change execute the whole file in the db (e.g. using phpAdmin). A superior setup would use docker and docker-compose instead of XAMMP and would install db and  reset all test data with a single command. This way the website is portable and can be tested only having the code.